# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_comment_api"

Tags: symfony4

In a symfony 4.4.9 installation I get the following error when I try to install fos_comment according to instructions:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "fos_comment_api" (in
>   "C:\wamp64\www\project\config/packages/routing.yaml"). Looked for
>   namespace "fos_comment_api", found ""framework", "twig", "twig_extra",
>   "web_profiler", "monolog", "debug", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations",
>   "sensio_framework_extra", "security", "maker", "oneup_uploader",
>   "knpu_oauth2_client", "msgphp_user", "msgphp_eav", "httplug",
>   "hwi_oauth", "jms_serializer", "fos_rest", "fos_comment",
>   "webpack_encore"" in
>   C:\wamp64\www\project\config/packages/routing.yaml (which is loaded
>   in resource "C:\wamp64\www\atractos\config/packages/routing.yaml").

Comment: I would like the one who put a negative to my question to explain why..

Comment: Didn't downvote so could not speak for that person, perhaps because there is no clear problem statement. Please accept your own answer (perfectly fine to do so) so that it will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put "fos_comment_api" in route.yaml and not in "routing.yaml"